# -ss and -itsoffset negative doesn' work FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

This is my command line:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -framerate 30 -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 0 -i title="Output" -f dshow
-i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -ss 1 -vcodec h264 -preset superfast
-pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -profile:v baseline
-level 3.1 -x264opts "keyint=60:min-keyint=60:no-scenecut" -ab 64k -ar 44100
-maxrate 2100k -minrate 2100k -bufsize 2100k -threads 1 "C:\Users\...\Desktop\TEST.mp4"
```

My audio is keeping a delay of 1 second by video. It means, video came 1 second first.
I was using `-ss 1` as you can see, but it just doesn't change anything.
I try to change to `-itsoffset -1` and all the possible syntaxes for both of them, but nothing happens.

When I try to do the video delay using a positive `-itsoffset`, ok, but audio nope.

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 0 -i title="Output" -f dshow
-i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -vcodec h264 -preset superfast
-pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -profile:v baseline
-level 3.1 -x264opts "keyint=60:min-keyint=60:no-scenecut" -af asetpts=PTS-(1/TB) -ab 64k -ar 44100
-maxrate 2100k -minrate 2100k -bufsize 2100k -threads 1 "C:\Users\...\Desktop\TEST.mp4"
```

The `asetpts` offsets the output timestamps of the audio by 1 second so the audio is brought forward by one second relative to the input sync.